# RuntimeException при транзакции фрагмента RecyclerView в TabLayout

Tags: android

Добрый день.
Не пойму принцип при котором во вложенном фрагменте начинаются транзакциии.

Есть главная активити CourierActivity

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.R;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.db.CourierDatabaseHelper;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.ui.AddClientFragment;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.ui.RequestDBSearchFragment;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.ui.RouteFragment;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.util.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class CourierActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddClientFragment.AddClientListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_courier);

        List<Fragment> stack = new ArrayList<>();
        stack.add(new AddClientFragment());
        stack.add(new RouteFragment());

        final TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.TabID);
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagerID);
        TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), stack);

        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(R.string.addClient));
        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(R.string.route));

        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));
        tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

                                          @Override
                                          public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                                              pager.setCurrentItem(tabs.getSelectedTabPosition());

                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                                          }

                                          @Override
                                          public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                                          }
                                      }
        );

        RequestDBSearchFragment fragment = new RequestDBSearchFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.place_holder, fragment);
        transaction.commit();


    }

    @Override
    public void changeDataText(String phoneNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        RouteFragment fragment = new RouteFragment();
        fragment.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
        fragment.setFirstName(firstName);
        fragment.setLastName(lastName);
        fragment.setAddress(address);
    }

    public void preRequestDB(String phoneNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        try {
            CourierDatabaseHelper courierDatabaseHelper = new CourierDatabaseHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = courierDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = null;

            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                cursor = db.query("courier",
                        new String[]{"PHONE"},
                        "PHONE = ?",
                        new String[]{phoneNumber + "%"},
                        null, null, null);
            }
            if (firstName != null) {
                cursor = db.query("courier",
                        new String[]{"FIRST_NAME"},
                        "LAST_NAME OR FIRST_NAME = ?",
                        new String[]{firstName + "%"},
                        null, null, null);
            }
            if (lastName != null) {
                cursor = db.query("courier",
                        new String[]{"LAST_NAME"},
                        "LAST_NAME OR FIRST_NAME = ?",
                        new String[]{lastName + "%"},
                        null, null, null);
            }
            if (address != null) {
                cursor = db.query("courier",
                        new String[]{"ADDRESS"},
                        "ADDRESS = ?",
                        new String[]{address + "%"},
                        null, null, null);
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

}

В ней создаются два фрагмента. точнее три один вложен в первый

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.R;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.util.DispatchEventChangeText;

public class AddClientFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


    public static interface AddClientListener {
        void changeDataText(String phoneNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address);
        void preRequestDB(String number, String phoneNumber, String flName, String address);
    }

    private AddClientListener mClientListener;
    private String mPhoneNumber;
    private String mFirstName;
    private String mLastName;
    private String mAddress;

    private EditText phoneNumber;
    private EditText firstName;
    private EditText lastName;
    private EditText address;

    private DispatchEventChangeText mDispatchEventChangeText;

    public AddClientFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.mClientListener = (AddClientListener) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_client, container, false);
        Button addButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        Button finishButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
        Button showMapButton = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.showMapButton);
        addButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        finishButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        showMapButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        phoneNumber = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        firstName = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        lastName = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        address = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.address);

        mDispatchEventChangeText = new DispatchEventChangeText();
        mPhoneNumber = checkLengthString(mDispatchEventChangeText.onChangeText(phoneNumber));
        mFirstName = checkLengthString(mDispatchEventChangeText.onChangeText(firstName));
        mLastName = checkLengthString(mDispatchEventChangeText.onChangeText(lastName));
        mAddress = checkLengthString(mDispatchEventChangeText.onChangeText(address));

        return layout;
    }

    public String checkLengthString(String string) {
        if (string != null) {
            if (string.length() >= 3) {
                request();
            }
        }
        return string;
    }

    public void request() {
        if (mClientListener != null) {
            mClientListener.preRequestDB(mPhoneNumber, mFirstName, mLastName, mAddress);
        }
    }

    public void changeText(String phoneNumber, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        if (mClientListener != null) {
            mClientListener.changeDataText(phoneNumber, firstName, lastName, address);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.addButton:
                addOnClick(view);
                break;
            case R.id.finishButton:
                finishOnClick(view);
                break;
            case R.id.showMapButton:
                showMapOnClick(view);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void addOnClick(View v) {
        mPhoneNumber = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
        mFirstName = firstName.getText().toString();
        mAddress = address.getText().toString();
        if ((mPhoneNumber != null && mPhoneNumber.length() != 0)
                && (mFirstName != null && mFirstName.length() != 0)
                && (mAddress != null && mAddress.length() != 0)) {
            changeText(mPhoneNumber, mFirstName, mLastName, mAddress);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.enterForm, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void finishOnClick(View v) {

    }

    public void showMapOnClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Это вложенный фрагмент в AddClientFragment

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.R;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.util.Client;
import vk.com.super_cargo.courier.util.RequestDBAdapter;

public class RequestDBSearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RequestDBAdapter mAdapter;

    public RequestDBSearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request_dbsearch, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.request_db_search_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        updateUI();
        return view;
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        List<Client> array = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(new Client("Peter","Colt","Chicago str. Major 32","0668741245",10));
        array.add(new Client("Philip","Morris","New Yourk av Prinstor 12","0664821645",3));
        array.add(new Client("Vasya","Pupkin","Mineapolis str. University 99","0664872211",7));

        mAdapter = new RequestDBAdapter(array);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

}
```

ошибка во время транзакции
StackTrace

```
02-07 20:08:04.408 21125-21125/vk.com.super_cargo.courier E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f0d007a (vk.com.super_cargo.courier:id/place_holder) for fragment RequestDBSearchFragment{124af378 #0 id=0x7f0d007a}
02-07 20:08:04.408 21125-21125/vk.com.super_cargo.courier E/FragmentManager: Activity state:
02-07 20:08:04.428 21125-21125/vk.com.super_cargo.courier E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: vk.com.super_cargo.courier, PID: 21125
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vk.com.super_cargo.courier/vk.com.super_cargo.courier.main.CourierActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d007a (vk.com.super_cargo.courier:id/place_holder) for fragment RequestDBSearchFragment{124af378 #0 id=0x7f0d007a}
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2491)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d007a (vk.com.super_cargo.courier:id/place_holder) for fragment RequestDBSearchFragment{124af378 #0 id=0x7f0d007a}
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1228)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6057)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2564) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:170) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1441) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
02-07 20:08:04.733 535-1352/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 360x360
```